# How to get facebook user birthday in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I use this code to get Facebook user informations. Most of informations are shown but the fact I need is user-birthday. There is no user-birthday in json array. The source code is [here.](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) Getting user information code is here

```
  public void getProfileInformation() {
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;
            try {
                // Facebook Profile JSON data
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                Log.i("profile",profile+"");
                // getting name of the user
                final String name = profile.getString("name");

                // getting email of the user
                final String email = profile.getString("email");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}
```

I need some advices. Please!!!

```
 02-03 21:29:35.700: D/Profile(1350): {"id":"1550015884","name":"Aung Htoon Kyaw","first_name":"Aung","middle_name":"Htoon","last_name":"Kyaw","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/aung.htoonkyaw","hometown":{"id":"105988982772786","name":"Yangon, Burma"},"location":{"id":"115804185098639","name":"Rangoon, Yangon, Burma"},"work":[{"employer":{"id":"107622942602570","name":"KMMGroup"}}],"favorite_athletes":[{"id":"450149851675417","name":"Gohan Kazuto Uzumaki"},{"id":"339211762793623","name":"Natsu Dragneel"},{"id":"1347550405383513","name":"Instagram Girls"},{"id":"331817313532412","name":"Hinata Hyuga"},{"id":"481643341874600","name":"Erza Scarlet"},{"id":"123163411183595","name":"Sanji"}],"education":[{"school":{"id":"109294362421667","name":"BEST High School"},"year":{"id":"140617569303679","name":"2007"},"type":"High School"},{"school":{"id":"104056766297330","name":"University of Computer Studies, Yangon"},"year":{"id":"141778012509913","name":"2008"},"type":"College","with":[{"id":"1059125424","name":"Nara ChannLynn"}]},{"school":{"id":"106398082730475","name":"UCSY"},"year":{"id":"141778012509913","name":"2008"},"type":"College"}],"gender":"male","email":"waptan22\u0040gmail.com","timezone":6.5,"locale":"en_US","verified":true,"updated_time":"2013-09-12T14:32:54+0000","username":"aung.htoonkyaw"}
```

This is logcat output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get user birthday and online status with facebook SDK for android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987118/how-to-get-user-birthday-and-online-status-with-facebook-sdk-for-android)

Answer (score 3):

to get more personal details you need a user permission, so pragmatically you need to add permission to your session and prompt it to the user to accept/deny this permission.

if you are following the `Androidhive` tutorial, I am afraid it is the old `Facebook SKD` so you need to read the new version of the SDK, to solve your problem check this [page out](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/fetch-user-data/) and specifically Step 2

on snippet of adding permission code:

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes"));
...
```

Comment: depend on your application, but for me I always add the permissions directly after he logs in.. so I show him all Facebook permissions at once. but if retrieving the user birthday is a rare operation then prompt it when it requires to get the birthday.

Comment: have you seen the link I provided in my answer if not here it is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/fetch-user-data/
I believe it is clear and started explaining fetching data from scratch only you have to do is create an application that can log in to user account