# How to get user birthday and online status with facebook SDK for android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am writing android application with SDK and I need to get **other** users's (not /me) birthday/age and online status? Is this possible? Tried following:

- accessing /{user-id} with GraphRequest, but this returns only name and id
- adding fields=age_range and user_birthday permissions doesn't help
- i am not able to make FQL queries, because they are deprecated since 2.0 and my access token which I get from android login, has FQL limitation.

Any ideas how else I can get user's ages/online statuses?

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, friend permissions have been removed with v2.0 of the Graph API. You can only get access to data of users who authorized your App (with the correct permissions). Meaning, birthday, age and online status is not available. You can´t even get the online status of an authorized user anymore, because that permission has been removed too.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: Dear @luschn, 1 more subquestions: is it possible to limit /searh?q=username results with sex/age restrictions?